# Programming Outlook Addin to automatically close and reload

Tags: c#, vsto

Is there a way to have an outlook add-in automatically close and reload at defined times / events.  I have an outlook addin that depends on a number of external services, and sometimes those external services can disconnect etc, but the outlook add-in struggles to realize it.  I was hoping to code something that would tell the add-in to automatically restart (and not all of outlook) at a certain time of day, just to make sure all the external connections are active and fresh (if that makes sense...).

I've coded the addin in C#, for Outlook 2010.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are fighting the symptoms here instead of solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below code to reload your addin, maybe put this in service or trigger it from any event

```
                    COMAddIns comAddIns = application.COMAddIns;
                COMAddIn addIn = null;

                foreach (COMAddIn addin in comAddIns)
                {
                    string.Equals(addin.Description, "Your Addin Name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        addIn = addin;                           
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (addIn != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Reloading....");
                    addIn.Connect = false;
                    addIn.Connect = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Reloading complete!");
                }
```